# Pass all arguments of a method into NSLog

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, reflection, arguments

I print out something to the console using `NSLog()`. Is there a way to pass all the current method's arguments to `NSLog()`, or any other function or method, without looking at each of them explicitly?

For example, I already have a macro that prints useful information to the console when I just put `LOGME` in my code. The macro will create a call to a singleton class's logging-method and pass several useful things like `_cmd` and other stuff.

I would also like to catch all the arguments of that method and pass them on for printing them out automatically. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use gdb. You can set a break point that logs the arguments to the method and continues.

If you insist on doing it the hard way... It's certainly not simple, but you could use the stack structure on a given architecture/ABI and make use of the Objective-C runtime to figure out how many arguments and of what size to look for. From here on out, I'm in unchartered territory; I've never done this nor would I ever bother. So YMMV...

Within your method, you can get the `Method` struct, then the number of arguments, then each argument type and the its size. You could then walk the stack from the address of the `self` parameter (i.e. `&self`), assuming you knew what you were doing...

```
Method method = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], _cmd);
unsigned nargs = method_getNumberOfArguments(method);
void *start = &self;
for(unsigned i = 0; i<nargs; i++) {
  char *argtype = method_copyArgumentType(method, i);
  //find arg size from argtype
  // walk stack given arg zie
  free(argtype);
}
```

Along the way you'd have to convert from the argtype string (using the [Objective-C type encodings](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH100-SW1)) to the size of each argument on the stack.

Of course then you'd have to derive the format string for each type, and call `NSLogv` with an appropriate variable argument array containing the arguments, copied from their location on the stack. Probably a lot more work than its worth. Use the debugger.

Comment: Wouldn't you want the address of the `self` variable? Starting from the object pointer *in* the `self` variable is not printing the method's arguments; it's printing the object's instance variables (probably as garbage, since you'd be using the method argument types for [mis]guidance).

Comment: Yes, absolutely, start from &self.

Comment: That's what I mean: Shouldn't `start` be initialized to `&self`, not `self`?

Comment: @Peter Of course. In the future, feel free to just edit away. I trust you more than me.

Comment: Great answer. But could you give me a hint how I can get the values from the stack. I would like to implement a logging routine that prints out the selector name and the argument values. It is just this final step missing ;) Thanks.

Comment: After doing a lot of research I ended up in this code: http://gist.github.com/653110 Maybe someone likes to contribute some more? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There’s no way to address all arguments in the preprocessor or Objective-C.

The only way I’m aware of is by use of the debugger. You can add a breakpoint action in Xcode to do this easily. Right click in the leftmost column of a code window, select "Built-in breakpoints" -> "Log breakpoint and arguments and auto-continue".

Comment: How does the debugger do it then?

Comment: The debugger has knowledge over the ABI (calling conventions) and uses debug symbols (created by the compiler) to map addresses in code and registers to locations and variables in source files. In short: It uses a whole bunch of tricks, that are not part of the language.