# objective C log method call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, debugging, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass all arguments of a method into NSLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797964/how-to-pass-all-arguments-of-a-method-into-nslog)

I can setup a macro printCommand to log the receiver and selector of a method call as follows:

```
#define printMethodCall NSLog (@"%@ %@", self, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```

Question -- can the above be extended to log all arguments that were passed with the method call, however few or many, and whatever types, they may be?

Comment: Perhaps a solution can be conjured up using [`NSMethodSignature`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMethodSignature_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSMethodSignature), [`NSInvocation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and friends?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this, but it's quite difficult.

The trick is to realize that a method is really just a function, and that you can create a `va_list` from the arguments, even if the method/function wasn't declared to take `...` in the signature.

The pseudo code would be something roughly like this:

```
va_list args;
// start your argument list after the "_cmd" argument
va_start(args, _cmd); 
// get the Method for this (instance) method
Method thisMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], _cmd);
// get the type encoding string for this method
const char *methodType = method_getTypeEncoding(thisMethod);
// use the type encoding string to make an NSMethodSignature
NSMethodSignature *signature = [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:methodType];

// iterate through all the arguments, skipping 0 (self) and 1 (_cmd)
for (NSUInteger i = 2; i < [signature numberOfArguments]; ++i) {
  // get the type of the argument
  const char *type = [signature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:i];

  // if this argument type is the same as an object, pull out an object
  if (strcmp(@encode(id), type) == 0) {
    id nextArg = va_arg(args, id);
    NSLog(@"object argument: %@", nextArg);

  // if this argument type is the same as a float, pull out a float
  } else if (strcmp(@encode(float), type) == 0) {
    float nextArg = va_arg(args, float);
    NSLog(@"float argument: %f", nextArg);
  } ...

  // repeat as necessary for all the types you care to log
}
// cleanup
va_end(args);
```

*Fortunately*, other people have wanted this sort of thing before and have come up with pretty much this same mechanism for doing it.  Here's an example of something that will `NSLog` an arbitrary expression:

http://vgable.com/blog/2010/08/19/the-most-useful-objective-c-code-ive-ever-written/